# MSets of different types interact badly

Tags: set, coq

I wanted to use sets, and for that tried to use the MSets library. But I need to write functions from one type of set to another type of set, and it interacts badly with Coq's module system.

Here is an example of the kind of problem I face. I want to have sets of a type `T` and sets of `T*T`. I added projection functions `proj1` and `proj2` to get a set of values from a set of pairs, and functions `add_l` and `add_r` to create a set of pair from a value and a set of values.

I instantiate my module with `nat`. I create a set of `nat` and call `add_l`, but Coq does not know that `SNat.t` and `S.S1.t` are the same. Here, I could create directly a set of type `S.S1.t`, but it will be more difficult if it has to interact with a more complex environment.

Is it possible to make Coq understand that `SNat.t` and `S.S1.t` are the same ? Or is there another solution to my problem ?

```
Require Import MSets.

Module DecidablePair (DT1:DecidableType) (DT2:DecidableType) <: DecidableType.
  Definition t : Type := DT1.t * DT2.t.
  Definition eq x y := DT1.eq (fst x) (fst y) /\ DT2.eq (snd x) (snd y).
  Lemma eq_equiv : Equivalence eq.
  Proof.
    split.
    - split; reflexivity.
    - split; symmetry; apply H.
    - split.
      + transitivity (fst y). apply H. apply H0.
      + transitivity (snd y). apply H. apply H0.
  Qed.
  Lemma eq_dec : forall x y, {eq x y} + {~ eq x y}.
  Proof.
    intros.
    destruct (DT1.eq_dec (fst x) (fst y)).
    - destruct (DT2.eq_dec (snd x) (snd y)).
      + left. split; assumption.
      + right. intros contra. apply n. apply contra.
    - right. intros contra. apply n. apply contra.
  Qed.
End DecidablePair.

Module MakePair (DT1: DecidableType) (DT2:DecidableType) <: WSets.
  Module S1 := MSetWeakList.Make DT1.
  Module S2 := MSetWeakList.Make DT2.
  Module DT := DecidablePair DT1 DT2.
  Include MSetWeakList.Make DT.

  Definition proj1 (s:t) := fold (fun x e => S1.add (fst x) e) s S1.empty.
  Definition proj2 (s:t) := fold (fun x e => S2.add (snd x) e) s S2.empty.

  Definition add_l (a:S1.elt) (s2:S2.t) := S2.fold (fun x e => add (a, x) e) s2 empty.
  Definition add_r (s1:S1.t) (a:S2.elt) := S1.fold (fun x e => add (x, a) e) s1 empty.
End MakePair.

Module SNat := MSetWeakList.Make Nat_as_DT.
Module S := MakePair Nat_as_DT Nat_as_DT.

Definition s1 := SNat.add 0 (SNat.add 4 SNat.empty).
Definition s := S.add_l 1 s1.
```